# jQuery find elements that match multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I have the following markup how can I check if each div inside each child does not have class hidden and if it has a data-access attribute that its value is equal to the value of the class in div with id=main

```
 <div id="main" class="agent">

   <div class="child">
     <div class="area hidden" >
        <div class="section">
           <div data-type="text" >
                 <input type="text" name="firstname">
             
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <div class="area" data-access="agent">
        <div class="section">
           <div data-type="text" >
                   <input type="text" name="lastname">
             
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <div class="area">
        <div class="section">
           <div data-type="text" >
                 <input type="text" name="refnumber">
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I can do the following but that only check if the divs don't contain the hidden class.

```
 $('.child').each(function(index, element) {

       $(element).find('.area:not(.hidden) .section:not(.hidden) div[data-type]:not(.hidden)').each(function(index, ele) {


       }

}
```

Along with checking if the divs do not contain a hidden class I want to check if each of those divs also contains a data-access attribute and if it does then check if the value is equal to the value of the class in `<div id="main" class="agent">`

Comment: Can simplify this significantly but not clear what higher level objective is. What do you need to do with results?

Comment: @charlietfl need to retrieve values of form inputs which sit inside div with data-type attribute if the div was displayed. If it was hidden then it can be ignored. visibilty of the containers can be toggled at three levels i.e. the three divs so need to check if any of them were hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You could first check if any child element has a class hidden with `.not` and `:has` and then also if any child element has data attribute `data-access` equal to class of element with id `main`.

```js
$('#main .child')
  .not(':has(.hidden)')
  .has(`[data-access="${$('#main').attr('class')}"]`)
  .css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="agent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="area hidden">
      <div class="section">
        <div data-type="text">1 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="area" data-access="agent">
      <div class="section">
        <div data-type="text">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="area">
      <div class="section">
        <div data-type="text">3 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `not()` , `filter()` and `hasClass()`

```js
$('.child').not(':has(.hidden)')
      .find('[data-access]')
      .filter(function(){      
          return $('#main').hasClass($(this).data('access'))
      })
      .end()
      .find('[data-type="text"]')
      .text('Matches main').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="agent">

   <div class="child">
     <div class="area hidden" >
        <div class="section">
           <div data-type="text" >Has hidden
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <div class="area" data-access="agent">
        <div class="section">
           <div data-type="text" >No hidden
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <div class="area">
        <div class="section">
           <div data-type="text" >No data access
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: if the divs have no hidden class or if they don't have data access attribute or if it does have a data access attribute and its value matches `agent`  then its visible

Comment: Not clear what implication of that comment is

Comment: @chalietfl if input field was displayed to user i want to retrieve the value - see updated markup. However the input fields visbility can be controlled by three parent divs. If the area div has a hidden class or a data-access attribute and the data-access attribute value does not match the value of the class in div with #main (in this case its agent) the input field was hidden so can be ignored. I need to check all three divs (area, section and data-type div to see if the input field was visible.

Comment: Ok, so what isn't working using my filter approach? Could probably also simplify to `$('.child input').filter(function(){ return !$(this).closest('.hidden').length})`

Comment: well for one your not checking all 3 parent divs of the input fields to see if any of them also contain a data-access attribute

Comment: Yes `.find('.area[data-access]')` does that. If that attribute can exist at different levels it is not clear in question or sample html

Comment: a section div can also contain a data-access attribute and so can the div with data-type. Its just not been shown in the markup

Comment: Ok ...see revised version using `end()`.  Level of the `data-access` within child not important now, just that it exists with a matching className

Comment: so as an agent accessing this form how would i retrieve the values of input fields inside child 2 and 3 as those would be the two fields displayed to the user?

Comment: Only child 2 has the matching data-access to #maiin though

Comment: some fields are only visible to agents. If the divs don't contain a hidden class or data-access attribute then they are visible to all users. If a guest user accessed the same form, they would only see the input field in child 3.

Comment: Suggest you update question with full requirements and scenarios. Comments seem to contradict what was asked

Comment: @cherlietfl see my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043350/jquery-loop-through-form-and-retrieve-field-labels-and-values-of-visible-inputs which contains full details of requirements.

Comment: Might be simplest to just do `$('.child input:visible')`. Will not return anything where any parent of the input is not visible

Comment: @adam78 see my answer there.

Comment: @charlietfl this wont work as form has pages and the holder div is contained inside pages. As user works through form, previous pages are hidden  but I need to present to user all fields that were displayed on all pages on the summary page.

Comment: *"form has pages"* ... none of that is clear in the question. Really going to need a [mcve] if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

So there is what is came up with hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        let listOfDivs = $('.child').children().filter((index, el) => !el.getAttribute('hidden') && el.getAttribute('data-access'))
        // lets check the 0 index & compare it with the #main class name
        if($('#main')[0] && listOfDivs[0] && $('#main')[0].getAttribute('class') === listOfDivs[0].getAttribute('data-access')){
          console.log("Matched",listOfDivs[0])
        }
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main" class="agent">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="area hidden">
        <div class="section">
          <div data-type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="area" data-access="agent">
        <div class="section">
          <div data-type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="area">
        <div class="section">
          <div data-type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you want to check a list

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        let listOfDivs = $('.child').children().filter((index, el) => !el.getAttribute('hidden') && el.getAttribute('data-access'))
        let main = $('#main').length ? $('#main')[0] : null
        
        if(main){
          let mainClassValue = main.getAttribute('class')
          for(let i = 0; i < listOfDivs.length; i++ ){
            if(mainClassValue === listOfDivs[i].getAttribute('data-access')){
              console.log("Matched",listOfDivs[i])
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: OP is using class hidden, not attribute and the `data-access` can exist on children of your children also. And what happens when `listOfDivs ` has length greater than one?

Comment: Nothing it will just check the first one but you want to check a whole list just wrap the if case inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

From your first description:

```html
<script>
$(function () {
    function findDivs() {
        var $root = $('#main');
        var rootClass = $root.get(0).className;

        // each div inside each child does not have class hidden...
        return $('#main > .child > div:not(.hidden)').filter(function (idx, elem) {
            var access = elem.dataset.access;

            //  ...if it has a data-access attribute...
            if (access) {
                // ..its value is equal to the value
                // of the class in div with id=main
                return access === rootClass;
            }

            // if it does not have data-access
            // attribute, return
            return true;
        });
    }

    // add this to an event handler
    console.log(findDivs());
});
</script>
```

Output:

```
0: <div class="area" data-access="agent">​
1: <div class="area">
```

If you want just the leaf divs with `[data-type]` you can add a `.find()` operation:

```html
<script>
$(function () {
    function findDivs() {
        var $root = $('#main');
        var rootClass = $root.get(0).className;

        return $('#main > .child > div:not(.hidden)')
            .filter(function (idx, elem) {
                var access = elem.dataset.access;

                if (access) {
                    return access === rootClass;
                }

                return true;
            })
            .find('[data-type]'); // ADDED
    }

    console.log(findDivs());
});
</script>
```

Output:

```
0: <div data-type="text">​
1: <div data-type="text">
```